# Cascading Merge Error

Tags: java, merge, cascading

I'm facing an issue while merging two pipes. On a higher level, the issue is perfectly summed up [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cascading-user/3_PiTtjtoTU/OWD1zco2CgAJ).

I have two pipes `Output1` and `Output2`, from where I'm retaining 2 fields, renaming them to bring to a single schema and merge.

```
Pipe Output1Retain = new Pipe("Output1Retain", new Retain(Output1, new Fields("output1fieldA", "output1fieldB")));
Pipe Output2Retain = new Pipe("Output2Retain", new Retain(Output2, new Fields("output2fieldA", "output2fieldB")));

Fields finalFields = new Fields("fieldA", "fieldB");

Pipe Output1Rename = new Pipe("Output1Rename",new Rename(Output1Retain, Fields.ALL, finalFields ));
Pipe Output2Rename = new Pipe("Output2Rename",new Rename(Output2Retain, Fields.ALL, finalFields ));

Pipe FinalOutput = new Merge("MergePipe",Output1Rename, Output2Rename);
```

The above code is giving me the below error from the flowplanner before the Cascading job even starts:

```
union of steps have 2 fewer elements than parent assembly MapReduceHadoopRuleRegistry, missing: [Each(Pass fileA through*Pass fileB through)[FilterNotNull[decl:ALL]], Each(Pass fileA through*Pass fileB through)[Identity[decl:ARGS]]]`
```

I see that this issue is fixed in Cascading 3.1.0 and I'm using 3.0.2 and unfortunately can't use 3.1.0. I tried using `Checkpoint` before the inputs to the `Merge` but it didn't help. I've abstracted a lot of detail on how `Output1` and `Output2` are prepared.

Is there any way out for this issue?